# How can I provide a telnet interface to my Java application?

Tags: java

I want to provide a telnet interface to my Java application, primarily so that developers can interact with the app, view debugging information, etc - before we've implemented our full end-user facing GUI.

Can anyone recommend an easy and effective way to do this?  I've looked at embedding the scala interpreter, but it doesn't seem to be accessible via telnet.  Ditto for Beanshell (which I'm not too keen on anyway as I believe its unmaintained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

- Grizzly for embedding a generic server (http://grizzly.java.net/)
- Mina is another similar option (http://mina.apache.org/)

Instead of Telnet, it might be easier to just embed a web server.  Not that a CLI isn't cool and all, but it might be a bit easier/more friendly.

- Jetty http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty
- Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html

JMX is great for monitoring but the UI isn't very good for 'writing' data.  NetBeans has some nice tutorial projects in it.

I think of all of the options above the embedded Jetty is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using JMX? It's built right into the jdk and can provide remote access via jconsole to any methods you configure it too.

Now it's not going to work exactly like ssh or telnet, so it might not meet your needs fully. But if your goals is access to invoking methods and debugging information remotely, that's kind of it's main purpose.

The bonus is after you build a UI you can still use the JMX stuff to monitor performance after it's goes live.

Comment: Hmm, thanks - I'll investigate JMX further.  Got any good pointers to info/tutorials?

Comment: Well Sun (Oracle now) provides one http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/tutorial/tutorialTOC.html and Spring has pretty good support for it. I'd recommend just googling around a bit. The formal documentation can be a little intimidating, but JMX is actually pretty easy to use. My only read advice is try to decouple JMX from your actual code as much as possible. Spring is great for that. But that's kind of good advice for most stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jsh](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) its good for telnet related stuff.

Comment: Right, but can it be integrated with some kind of shell, like the Scala REPL or even Beanshell?  Also, I don't really need the connection to be encrypted as it will mainly be local.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and came up with a [slightly ugly combination](https://github.com/permazen/permazen/blob/master/permazen-cli-telnet/src/main/java/io/permazen/cli/telnet/TelnetConsole.java) of [nvt4j](https://github.com/archiecobbs/nvt4j) (telnet server code) plus [JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline2) (Java command line history editor, tab completion, etc.). My application listens on localhost for telnet connections and runs a CLI console loop when it gets a connection.

One key trick is to get the rows and columns information (which is sent via the telnet protocol) transferred from nvt4j to JLine so things don't go haywire when you reach the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a line-mode interface via Telnet, you could use my Java class  [TelnetStdioRedirector](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/TelnetStdioRedirector/).